# Get registered filters in correct order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to list all my filters in correct order as I have some filters that must be first in the filterchain.

From the ServletContext I can fetch all filters like this:

```
    Map<String, ? extends FilterRegistration> filters = servletContext.getFilterRegistrations();
    filters.forEach((k,v) -> {
        System.out.println(k);
        System.out.println(v.getClassName());
    });
```

Since this is a Map and unordered this will print out:

```
Key: webMvcMetricsFilter
Classname: org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter
Key: requestContextFilter
Classname: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter
Key: MyCustomFilterThatNeedsToBeFirst
Classname: my.custom.filter.MyCustomFilterThatNeedsToBeFirst
Key: Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter
Classname: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter
Key: characterEncodingFilter
Classname: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter
Key: springSecurityFilterChain
Classname: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean$1
Key: formContentFilter
Classname: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter
```

How can I fetch the filterchain in a list that is ordered so I  can verify that `MyCustomFilterThatNeedsToBeFirst` is the first filter in the filterchain?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to get your custom filter by key of the map and process it and then remove that from the map, and then iterate over the rest of the map.

```
    Map<String, ? extends FilterRegistration> filters = servletContext.getFilterRegistrations();
processFilter(filters.get("MyCustomFilterThatNeedsToBeFirst"))
filters.entrySet().stream().filter(key -> key.equals("MyCustomFilterThatNeedsToBeFirst"))
                    .forEach((k,v) -> processFilter(v));
```

another approach I can think of is, you can create a double ended queue using 
[deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) where you create the deque by iterating the map and putting the specific `MyCustomFilterThatNeedsToBeFirst` to the front of the deque and the rest of them to the back. and then finally process the items in the deque one by one.

Hope it helps

Edit======================================

If you need to set precedence to a filter then you can do that by adding the annotation `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` to the filter class.  You can also give a numbered precedence as well like `@Order(1)`

Comment: Currently I don't need to process the filters at this moment. I just need to list all filters registered in spring so I can verify that MyCustomFilterThatNeedsToBeFirst is the first in the list of filters

Comment: So you mean that you need your custom filter should be the one that is processed first four every request that is coming in?

Comment: I have edited my answer to suit that case as well, you can check that